# (Pseudo-)tensor densities as sections of bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

In the wiki article on tensor densities (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_density) it is mentioned that this notion may be understood in terms of sections of tensor product of the density bundle with tensor bundles. I would like to clarify if I am correct in thinking that (due to the determinant in transition functions being/not being taken with absoulte value) this only works for pseudotensor densities -- tensor densities are instead sections of tensor product of just the determinant bundle with tensor bundles?

Answer (score 1):

No this also works for true tensor densities. Densities are sections of an honest natural bundle (which is associated to the frame bundle of the manifold) and forming the tensor product of this bundle with a tensor bundle is no problem. It is just not so easy to construct the density bundle from tensor bundles (but you can take the square root of the square of the determinant bundle). A description of densities this spirit (in slightly different language  via cocycles of transitions functions) can be found in Section 10 of P. Michor's "Topics in Differential Geometry".

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "honest natural bundle" (and google is not helpful). Is it the same as the associated bundle presented in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold (the density bundle)?

Comment: What I mean by "natural bundle" is a functor on the category of smooth manifolds of fixed dimension and local diffeomorphisms. In that sense the density bundle is "as good" as any tensor bundle (which is what I meant by saying that it is an "honest" natural bundle). One of the ways of seeing this is to realize the density bundle as an associated bundle to the frame bundle as in the link in your comment.